# User RDS CALs are not issued when RDS role is istalled on Server 2012 R2 in a workgroup. Will it work after the grace period?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rds, workgroup

I installed RDS on a Windows 2012 R2 server in a workgroup (no AD) following the instructions from [kb2833839](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2833839) article. Besides the fact that I have no RDS Manager, everything seems to work fine. The licensing mode has been set to Per User (mode 4).

I can connect RDS clients with no message about the 120 days grace period.
But I notice in RDS Licence server that the User CALs are not issued when RDS clients are connected to the server.

Will I run into a problem when the 120 days grace perios will end?
Thank's in advance for your expertise,

François

Answer (score 2):

Per-User Client Access Licenses (CALs) tracking and reporting is not available in a workgroup. It only works in an AD domain. If your license server is activated and you're not seeing any error messages about the RDSH server being in a grace period, I'd say you're fine.

Per [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754625.aspx):

> RDS Per User CAL tracking and reporting is not supported in workgroup mode.

Run the "RD Licensing Diagnoser" and see what it says.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have installed the RDS role, you will have to install the RDS license manager on a License server, and install the RD cals license before the grace period ends. The license should be loaded from the Licensing server for number of cals, However , there is no limit on the number of connection during the grace period.

[image: Screenshot]